# Saving file in node.js

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to do a simple user profile picture upload but can't figure it out.

I'm using Node, Express, and Formidable. Here's my route in Express:

```
// Change Profile Picture
exports.changeProfilePicture = function(req, res) {

     var user = new Parse.User.current();
     var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

     form.on('file', function(name, file) {

        console.log("name = " + name);
        console.log("file = " + file);

        var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, {base64: file.toString('base64', 0, file.length)}); // Convert from buffer object to array

        parseFile.save().then(function() {

          // The file has been saved to Parse. file's URL is only available 
          //after you save the file or after you get the file from a Parse.Object.
          //Get the function url() on the Parse.File object.
          var url = parseFile.url();

          user.set('profilePictureMedium', url);

          user.save().then(function() {
                response.success("Successfully added add profile picture medium.");
            }, function(error) {
                response.error("Could not add profile picture medium.");

            });
          }, 
          function(error) {
            // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
          });
     });
}
```

I'm following [this question](https://www.parse.com/questions/is-it-possible-to-save-a-parsefile-from-cloud-code) on the Parse forum and Alberto's answer which led me to convert the file data with the line `var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, {base64: file.toString('base64', 0, file.length)});`

The file saves fine but when I set it on the `user` object and then try to save I get this error:

```
Error: 111 invalid type for key profilePictureMedium, expected file, but got string
```

Obviously I set the file to a string per Alberto's answer.

---

However, when I had this previously and didn't convert the file:

```
var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
```

I would get this error:

```
15:56:09 web.1  |         self._previousSave = self._source.then(function(base64, type) {
15:56:09 web.1  |                                           ^
15:56:09 web.1  | TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined
```

---

**UPDATE**: I'm able to save the file to user now. However, the saved file is broken. Here's the relevant code:

```
    var parseFile = new Parse.File(filename, {base64: file.toString('base64', 0, file.length)});
    console.log(file);
    console.log(parseFile);
```

console.log(file):

```
12:47:18 web.1  | { _readableState: 
12:47:18 web.1  |    { highWaterMark: 16384,
12:47:18 web.1  |      buffer: [],
12:47:18 web.1  |      length: 0,
12:47:18 web.1  |      pipes: null,
12:47:18 web.1  |      pipesCount: 0,
12:47:18 web.1  |      flowing: false,
12:47:18 web.1  |      ended: false,
12:47:18 web.1  |      endEmitted: false,
12:47:18 web.1  |      reading: false,
12:47:18 web.1  |      calledRead: false,
12:47:18 web.1  |      sync: true,
12:47:18 web.1  |      needReadable: false,
12:47:18 web.1  |      emittedReadable: false,
12:47:18 web.1  |      readableListening: false,
12:47:18 web.1  |      objectMode: false,
12:47:18 web.1  |      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
12:47:18 web.1  |      ranOut: false,
12:47:18 web.1  |      awaitDrain: 0,
12:47:18 web.1  |      readingMore: false,
12:47:18 web.1  |      oldMode: false,
12:47:18 web.1  |      decoder: null,
12:47:18 web.1  |      encoding: null },
12:47:18 web.1  |   readable: true,
12:47:18 web.1  |   domain: null,
12:47:18 web.1  |   _events: { end: [Function] },
12:47:18 web.1  |   _maxListeners: 10,
12:47:18 web.1  |   truncated: false,
12:47:18 web.1  |   _read: [Function] }
```

console.log(parseFile):

```
12:47:18 web.1  | parseFile = 
12:47:18 web.1  | { _name: 'monkey_mad.jpg',
12:47:18 web.1  |   _source: 
12:47:18 web.1  |    { _resolved: true,
12:47:18 web.1  |      _rejected: false,
12:47:18 web.1  |      _resolvedCallbacks: [],
12:47:18 web.1  |      _rejectedCallbacks: [],
12:47:18 web.1  |      _result: { '0': '[object Object]', '1': 'image/jpeg' } } }
```

Comment: if the column is already of type file, set the file object instead of the url..  user.set('profilePictureMedium', parseFile);

Comment: @Fosco So I'm now able to set the file and save it to user. However, the file link is now broken... BTW, thanks for all your help this past week.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear your column "profilePictureMedium" is of type `File` but you are giving it just the string URL.

Instead you should set the column to the file you just uploaded, as per Fosco's comment:

```
user.set('profilePictureMedium', parseFile);
```